# How to access the MasterLeague training menu?

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2009

I'm currently playing Pro Evolution Soccer 2009 - the master league mode. Toward the end of the season I get a message stating -

> During the off-season transfer period you can also developer players through training sessions. Select the player(s) you want to train and then set the training menu.

I've searched high and low for this menu, even wondering if it was a mistake. But then I found a picture in Italian on the web but I still don't know how to get there.

[image]

So can anyone tell me exactly how to get to this menu option?